# Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './charset.js'

Tags: javascript, socket.io, npm, gulp

Why am I getting this error?

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module './charset.js'
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Application built with Flux and React.js",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Joe Collins",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "*",
    "flux": "*",
    "gulp": "*",
    "reactify": "*",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "*",
    "object-assign": "*"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bufferutil": "^1.2.1",
    "charset": "^1.0.0",
    "http": "0.0.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "socket.io": "^1.4.5",
    "utf-8-validate": "^1.2.1"
  }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var reactify = require('reactify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    browserify('./src/js/main.js')
        .transform('reactify')
        .bundle()
        .pipe(source('main.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'))
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
    gulp.src('src/index.html')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    gulp.src('src/css/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css'));
    gulp.src('src/js/vendors/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['browserify', 'copy'], function() {
    return gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', ['browserify', 'copy']);
});
```

App.js

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use socket.io-client for client side stuff.  I have a hunch that charset.js uses a binary, or something that can't be converted to the browser.

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem but with some other  module  I did reinstall with latest and it is working for me

**Problem**

```
Error: Cannot find module './charset.js'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:534:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1269:46)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:464:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:577:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1153:31)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at /snapshot/html/config/configurator-file-api/node_modules/accepts/node_modules/negotiator/lib/negotiator.js:21:16
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/html/config/configurator-file-api/node_modules/accepts/node_modules/negotiator/lib/negotiator.js:19:18)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1243:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:644:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:552:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:495:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:487:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:577:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1153:31)
```

**Solution**

cd /var/html/config/configurator-file-api/node_modules/accepts/

npm uninstall negotiator --save

npm install negotiator --save

Yes it is working